# Why it throw me the error: TypeError: project.save is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

My controller file:

```
'use strict'

var Project = require('../models/project');

function saveProject(req, res){  

    var project = new Project();

    Project.find({name: project.name}, (err, project)=>{

        if(err) return res.status(500).send({message: 'Error en la peticion'});

        if(project && project.length >=1){
            return res.status(404).send({message: 'El proyecto ya existe en la base dedatos'});
        }else{

            project.save((err, projectStored)=>{

                if(err) return res.status(500).send({message: 'Error en la peticion'});

                if(!projectStored) return res.status(404).send({message: 'No se ha podido salvar el proyecto'});

                return res.status(200).send({project: projectStored});
            });
        }         
    });
}

module.exports = {
    saveProject
}
```

My model file:

```
'use strict'

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ProjectSchema = Schema({

    name: String,
    description: String,
    category: String, 
    year: Number,
    langs: String,
    image: String    

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Project', ProjectSchema);
```

My Routes file:

```
'use strict'

var express = require('express');
var projectController = require('../controllers/project');

var api = express.Router();

// Middlewares de Autenticacion


// Llamamos a los metodos y le definimos su ruta
api.post('/save-project', projectController.saveProject);

// Exportamos
module.exports = api;
```

Comment: You also have two variables named `project`, one you created with `new Project()` and one you declared as a function parameter to the `.find()` callback.  Those will conflict.  Change the name of one of them and then you can access both with their appropriate names.

Comment: Thanks friend, that was really what was wrong. I have already solved it and thanks to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
Project.find({name: project.name}, (err, project)=>{ ...
                                         ^^^^^^^ you are receiving `project` as argument
```

pay attention that project is the argument, not that project from variable you defined just one line above:

```
var project = new Project();
```

This must be the cause of your false expectations.

Comment: Thanks friend, that was really what was wrong. I have already solved it and thanks to you too,

Comment: You are welcome! Thanks for not forgetting selecting best answer